# Generate crowd SSO token from custom app

Tags: single-sign-on, atlassian-plugin-sdk, atlassian-crowd

How can I have to generate SSO token after crowd login (via rest service) for case when I can use this token for login to crowd?
I mean I use

```
crowdClient.authenticateUser(...)
```

and after that

```
crowdClient.authenticateSSOUser
```

with same credentials (and I tried in reverse order)

I store this token in crowd.token_key session variable, but Crowd doesn't authenticate me by this token.

But if I logged in crowd first my app recognize this token.

I think it should be depends from ValidationFactor, but I don't know which I should to use.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in CROWD source code. You need to generate token with next validation factors:

```
 List<ValidationFactor> validationFactors = new ArrayList<>();
 validationFactors.add(new ValidationFactor(ValidationFactor.REMOTE_ADDRESS, request.getRemoteAddr()));
 String remoteAddressXForwardFor = request.getHeader(ValidationFactor.X_FORWARDED_FOR);
 if (remoteAddressXForwardFor != null && !remoteAddressXForwardFor.equals(request.getRemoteAddr())) {
     validationFactors.add(new ValidationFactor(ValidationFactor.X_FORWARDED_FOR, remoteAddressXForwardFor));
 }
```